# Prove $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x^2}{2x^2 - 1}= \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Given  $\epsilon>0$, there exist $M$, such that $\forall x \geq M$ which leads to  $$\left| \frac{x^2}{2x^2 - 1} - \frac{1}{2}\right| < \epsilon$$
Simplify.
$$\left|\frac{1}{4x^2 - 2}\right|<\epsilon$$
Since x going to infinity, we may drop absolute value sign, we get $$\sqrt{\frac{1+2\epsilon}{4\epsilon}} < x$$

Now I'm stepping in something wrong. Let $$M =\sqrt{\frac{1+2\epsilon}{4\epsilon}}$$

Which should mean that any $x>M$ will suffice for definition of a limit.
But if I plug in $M$ into $$\left|\frac{x^2}{2x^2 - 1} - \frac{1}{2}\right| < \epsilon$$ I'll get $\epsilon < \epsilon$.
But if $x$ is bigger than $M$, result will be less than  $\epsilon$, because numenator is smaller than denominator. I sort of proved it(?) , but something in my logic is wrong.
I suppose my suggestion should have strict inequality? $\forall x > M$

Comment: Yes, take $x>M$ and you are in good shape.

Comment: Either take $M$ slightly bigger, or let $x>M$ or use non-strict inequality. Either way you're good.

Comment: @Michal Adamaszek I used M+1 and got a big unwieldy fraction, it scared me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can also simplify noting that eventually

$$\left|\frac{1}{4x^2 - 2}\right|<\frac1{x^2}$$

and then for $\frac1{x^2}\le \varepsilon \iff x\ge M=\frac1{\sqrt \varepsilon}$

$$\left|\frac{1}{4x^2 - 2}\right|<\varepsilon$$